# Will it hurt my career to work as a graphic designer in a startup for beauty and skin care?

Tags: designers, advertising

I got a job offer from a startup for beauty and skin care. There's a team of developer, marketers, social media and accountants. Their treatment and sales team works somewhere else, while the office work is different (like I won't see treatments and doctors in front of me in office) There was a designer before, who quit, and now they have an offer. I applied and I got selected.

I have to mostly design their social media posts (like human faces with skin care content, showing features, comparisons, offers, special events related posts like festivals). Which I don't have any problem with.

So far I had experience of working in a tech startup and a digital marketing agency. My only dilemma is that the company is more related to women beauty and skin care. So do graphic designers generally work in such places or is it not suited for designers for personal and professional growth? Would it be bad for me to work in that environment, as a designer?

Comment: The 3 immediate downvotes were the result of spam flags which were raised about your question, because your question was identified as substantially similar to the *large* amount of spam Stack Exchange routinely gets from skin care companies. It did not help that this is your second time posting almost exactly the same question, just [on a different SE site](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/140315). One of those spam flags has been retracted (removing the downvote). The users who raised the other two of the initial three have been notified and asked to reevaluate the question.

Comment: Moderator’s notice: I rejected the spam flags (thus undoing the downvotes) and approved an edit removing the links. As pointed out by others above, these flags were mostly the result of bad luck, as your post had a couple of features that we normally see in spam. I removed the links nonetheless as we want questions to be of general use and not about evaluating the specific company you are considering to join. With that being said: Welcome to Graphic Design SE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please take the [tour]. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: What specifically are you worried about happening if you accept the position? Are you concerned that it might harm your reputation in some way, or that it would not look good on a resume? If you can come up with specific reasons your'e concerned, that may help you find the answer.

Comment: *Large amount of spam Stack Exchange routinely gets from skin care companies* - this is close to the thought that I had when reading the title of the question. The main thing that may hurt your carreer (but probably won't), is the reputation of skin care and wellness companies, their dishonest marketing and predatory practices. Somebody may (but probably won't) think that working for them says something about your own sense of morality.

Comment: Since the user *never* returned... I'd wager the spam flags were completely warranted.

Answer (score 19):

Graphic designers work in all shapes and sizes of companies selling all types of product and services. There's no field which is *not* suited for a graphic designer if the company markets *anything* to customers or clients, in any visual manner, in any medium.

As for "personal and professional growth"... that can't really be answered by anyone other than you. No one here is familiar with the company, your skills, your career goals, or you personally.

Comment: My brother started doing GD for Lucent technologies; then worked for Heinz Sauces and Condiments; worked free-lance for a while doing technical manuals (nuclear plant instruction manuals;) and now designs billboards and giant illuminated signage.

Answer (score 8):

The good news is your question is almost bizarre:

- Yes, beauty and fashion is - of course - one of the **major and most lucrative** fields of Graphic Design.

For example ... of the many well-known designers I'm either friends with or work with frequently, the most successful one indeed focusses on .. beauty and fashion!

(You mention "skin care" specifically - even better, one of the most lucrative and dynamic subfields.)

Good luck and enjoy.

Answer (score 6):

Probably not going to hurt you, skin care is just like any other field and you can build a relevant portfolio taking this job. Time will tell if this job helps your career or not. Also, ask yourself this:

- why has the previous designer quit?
- do you have any better career opportunities at the moment?